# "Session expired" Error with Selenium Python in Chrome just immediately after very few seconds of logging in

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, wait, expected-condition

I have a selenium program written in python. It has to login, load the page and the navigate to a certain page to do some functionalties. But, When I run the script using chrome, the script performs hardly any functioning, and gives a dialog box saying "Your session is expired". Sometimes it logs in and then gives this error, many other times, it doesn't even login using the given credentials.

The whole process it performed would be hardly 5 seconds and then throws me this error "Session expired". I have wait statements with expected conditions (until delaytime = 30), implicit waits(Max wait = 10) and also time(Maximum 3).sleep commands in my script. I am totally clueless why is this happening like this.

If I try to login manually, it is all functioning well. But when I try to login with selenium expected conditions, it is failing. But to my surprise, it had been logging in, functioning well all till before 3 days. Now suddenly this happened. But it has no issues when done manually.

I wish someone who is aware of such a situation, could please share their knowledge to help me.
Thanks in advance for extending your hand to brighten the life of someone with your knowledge!